# Page Jump on PHP Form Submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i'm working on a php form on a one pager website. i'm running into two issues. the first is that the form jumps to the top of the page when submitted. i've tried a few different things to prevent this but none seem to be working out. the second is that the form session stays initiated, resulting in blank resubmissions in my DB if user hits ctrl-r.

if someone know how to negate the page jump onsubmit i'm experiencing that would be amazing.

thanks,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'XXX';
$dbuser = 'XXX';
$dbpass = 'XXX';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $form_name     = addslashes ($_POST['form_name']);
   $form_email    = addslashes ($_POST['form_email']);
   $form_phone    = addslashes ($_POST['form_phone']);
   $form_linkedin = addslashes ($_POST['form_linkedin']);

   $form_q1       = addslashes ($_POST['form_q1']);
   $form_q2       = addslashes ($_POST['form_q2']);
   $form_q3       = addslashes ($_POST['form_q3']);
   $form_q4       = addslashes ($_POST['form_q4']);
   $form_q5       = addslashes ($_POST['form_q5']);
}
else
{

   $form_name     =  $_POST['form_name'];
   $form_email    =  $_POST['form_email'];
   $form_phone    =  $_POST['form_phone'];
   $form_linkedin =  $_POST['form_linkedin'];

   $form_q1       =  $_POST['form_q1'];
   $form_q2       =  $_POST['form_q2'];
   $form_q3       =  $_POST['form_q3'];
   $form_q4       =  $_POST['form_q4'];
   $form_q5       =  $_POST['form_q5'];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO XXX".
       "(form_name, form_email, form_phone, form_linkedin, form_q1, form_q2, form_q3, form_q4, form_q5) ".
       "VALUES('$form_name','$form_email','$form_phone', '$form_linkedin', '$form_q1', '$form_q2', '$form_q3', '$form_q4', NOW())";
mysql_select_db('XXX');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die("<section id='thank_you'><h1>SOMETHING WENT WRONG</h1><p class='about_body_txt'>Click <a href='XXX'>here</a> to resubmit</p></section>"); 
}
    echo("<section id='thank_you'><h1>THANK YOU</h1><p class='about_body_txt'>Selected participants will be notified by July 8, 2014. Click <a href='XXX'>here</a> to return to the main site.</p></section>");
    mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
  <form id="gfbm_form" class="theForm" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

                    <h2>APPLICATIONS DUE<br/>
                <span class="medium_txt">THURSDAY, JULY 3RD AT 5PM, EST.</span></h2>



                    <div class="application">

                        <ul>
                            <li class="small_field">
                                <span><label class="label_field">Name</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <input id="form_name" class="name input_field" type="text" name="form_name" />
                            </li>

                            <li class="small_field">
                                <span><label class="label_field">Email</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <input id="form_email" class="email input_field" type="text" name="form_email" />
                            </li>

                            <li class="small_field_2">
                                <span><label class="label_field">Phone</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <input id="form_phone" class="phone input_field" type="text" name="form_phone" />
                            </li>


                            <li class="small_field_2">
                                <span><label class="label_field">LinkedIn</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <input id="form_linkedin" class="linkedin input_field" type="text" name="form_linkedin" />
                            </li>


                            <li class="essay_question">
                                <span><label class="label_field">QUESTION 1</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <textarea id="form_q1" class="q1 input_field_big" type="text" name="form_q1"></textarea>
                            </li>

                            <li class="essay_question">
                                <span><label class="label_field">QUESTION 2</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <textarea id="form_q2" class="q2 input_field_big" type="text" name="form_q2"></textarea>
                            </li>


                            <li class="essay_question">
                                <span><label class="label_field">QUESTION 3</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <textarea id="form_q3" class="q3 input_field_big" type="text" name="form_q3"></textarea>
                            </li>


                            <li class="essay_question">
                                <span><label class="label_field">QUESTION 4</label></span>
                                <br/>
                                <textarea id="form_q4" class="q4 input_field_big" type="text" name="form_q4"></textarea>
                            </li>
                        </ul>



                            <input type="checkbox" required id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" />
                            <label class="check_text">
                                <p>YES, I'LL BE AVAILABLE FOR ALL OF THOSE DATES.</p>
                            </label>


                            <input type="checkbox" required id="checkbox-2-2" />
                            <label class="check_text">
                                <p>I have read and understand the terms and conditions.</p>
                            </label>



<input name="add" type="submit" class="submit btn btn-default" id='submit' value="APPLY">




                </form>
```

Comment: You're gonna hear this a lot, DON'T USE THE DEPRACATED MYSQL_ STATEMENTS.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274683/how-to-stop-a-page-jumping-to-the-top-once-a-form-is-submitted or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715387/how-to-jump-to-anchor-on-submit-not-to-top-of-page

Comment: @rlb.usa i hadn't seen this. i'm going to close this posting out. thanks!

Comment: @unfollow No problem buddy! Sometimes Google isn't mind-ready enough, ya know? Can't tell you how many times I've started a question and found the answer here. Hope you keep comin' back. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`submit` submits the page and thus reloads it, putting you at the top again.  You could create an HTML anchor and trigger that with an onload javascript event or something to move the user back to the same location, but that is about the extent.

Comment: Or use AJAX to submit the form and literally stay on the same page (vs submitting to the same URL).

Answer (score -2):

It's normal to jump to top of the page temporary and then back to your comment you posted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).